# Unlock review vote in proposed changes after a draft is updated

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, documentation, rejected-edits, documentation-proposals

It is currently not possible to approve a draft you've previously rejected, when the draft is edited.

Even if the draft was retracted, modified and re-submitted, there is no way for a reviewer to undo his "reject" vote.

Note: a edit *shouldn't* reset these votes, as that'd be a recipe for abuse. It should merely enable a reviewer to change his existing vote, much like up/downvotes on posts get unlocked after an edit.